# null with PHP < and > operators

Tags: php, null, comparison, mapping, operators

Can somebody explain how null is mapped in these statements?

```
null>0; //=> bool(false)
null<0; //=> bool(false)
null==0; //=> bool(true)
```

but

```
null<-1; // => bool(true)
```

I assume it's some mapping problem, but can't crack it.

Tried with PHP 5.3.5-1 with Suhosin-Patch.

Comment: Erm, what is it you are trying to do? All those statements are valid.

Comment: Use `===` type checked equality if you want accuracy

Comment: If only PHP's null was like an SQL null...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I would point you to a few pages: 
http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

So in your final example:

```
null<-1 => bool(true)
```

The `null` is cast to `false` and the `-1` is cast to `true`, `false` is less than `true`

In your first two examples `null` is cast to `false` and `0` is cast to `false`, `false` is not less than or greater than `false` but is equal to it.

Ohh the fun of `null` ! :D

Comment: thks for clarification :D, quite curious why the null is casted to bool instead of (int) when having (int) on the other side of <

Comment: @SzymonLukaszczyk - I wondered that also, but the second link has a table "Comparison with Various Types" that answers this in its second line: if the first operand is null, the operands are both converted to boolean.